# Angular js- When I Make a change in one scope variable it also changes other scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As per title I have uploaded my code on fiddle here is the link visit
https://jsfiddle.net/owze1rcj/ 
when I make changes myAppObjects variable. changes also reflect in other variable.
here is my code
(HTML part)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="appObj in myAppObjects">
        <td>{{appObj.id}}
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="appObj.cb1"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="appObj.cb2"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="appObj.cb3"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="appObj.cb4"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="appObj.cb5"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <pre>
   first {{myAppObjects | json}}
    second {{AppObjects | json}}
    </pre>

</div>
```

(Controller part)

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var a =[
        {
        id: 1,
        cb1: true,
        cb2: false,
        cb3: true,
        cb4: true,
        cb5: false
        }];

    $scope.myAppObjects = a;
    $scope.AppObjects = a;


}
```

Comment: because both variable are objects, & they are referring to same reference

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: What is the problem? The code you have posted is working as expected

Comment: Actually I'm new to js. I'm changing $scope.myAppObjects why is $scope.AppObjects also getting changed. Thats I m not getting

Answer (score 2):

First Understand the concept of Deep copy and Shallow Copy

**Shallow copy**

> `Shallow copy` has the top level object and points to the same object.

Hence, When you **directly copy the one scope variable** to other it **creates a shallow copy**.

```
  $scope.firstVar = $scope.secondVar;
```

Here, both `firstVar` and `secondVar` are connected to each other in above example.

**Deep copy**

> `Deep copy` has all of the objects of the copied object at all levels and points to the different object.

`angular.copy` **Creates a deep copy of source,** which should be an object or an array.

```
$scope.firstVar = angular.copy($scope.secondVar);
```

Here, both `firstVar` and `secondVar` are two different variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
var a =[
    {
    id: 1,
    cb1: true,
    cb2: false,
    cb3: true,
    cb4: true,
    cb5: false
    }];

$scope.myAppObjects = angular.copy(a);
$scope.AppObjects = angular.copy(a);
}
```

Use angular.copy() method for assigning values, it won't copy variable references